# Problema de utilizar common controls 32 bit em 64 bit

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, controles

Estou tendo um problema com os common controls no excel 64-bit(checkbox por exemplo), são necessários para rodar um código em VBA porém na versão 64 bit não consigo selecioná-los.

OBS: os common controls foram implemantados em excel 32 bit

Comment: Parece que não tem solução, meu caro. Para usar seus controles ActiveX e mesmo alguns códigos VBA, você vai precisar desinstalar o Office 64-bit e reinstalar o 32-bit. Veja: https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Choose-the-32-bit-or-64-bit-version-of-Office-2dee7807-8f95-4d0c-b5fe-6c6f49b8d261?CorrelationId=e10e24e6-159a-41b7-81cf-eda5d6e58c10&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#BKMK_Limitations64bit

Answer (score 2):

Eu aqui também utilizo o windows10 com o office365 e consigo rodar meus códigos em vba utilizando controles do excel 32 bit. 
Eu simplesmente criei um diretório no Windows\system32 e copiei as ocx e dll neste diretório e depois registrei. regsv32 c:\windows\system32\arquivo.ocx